# How to pass a Select Expression with a statement body to .Select() instead of declaring inline

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code currently in a method.  This works without any issue.

```
    // databaseHelper.GetPatientsForCompanyAsync uses Dapper to return a collection
    // of Patient Objects.  The .Select is used to transform the collection
    // into a set of anonymous types so that when they are serialized to
    // to json, the property names will be what the receiving API wants
    public async Task SyncPatientData(ProcessType processType)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"Started SyncPatientData");
        var companies = await GetCompanySettingsAsync(processType);
         
        foreach (var company in companies)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Processing company {company.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName} of {companies.Count()}");
            try
            {
                DateTime startDate = company.SyncData.LastPatientSyncDate.HasValue ? company.SyncData.LastPatientSyncDate.Value : company.UpdoxSyncData.CurrentDatabaseDate.AddYears(-3);

                var data = await databaseHelper.GetPatientsForCompanyAsync(company, startDate);
                logger.LogInformation($"Company: {company.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName} - Loaded: {data.Count()} Patients");
                var manager = new ContentManager(company, appConfiguration);
                var responses = await manager.PostEntityData("patients", appConfiguration.PatientUrl, data.Select(x => new
                {
                    id = x.patient_id.ToString(),
                    internalId = x.patient_id.ToString(),
                    firstName = x.first_name,
                    middleName = x.middle_name,
                    lastName = x.last_name,
                    emailAddress = x.email,
                    homePhone = x.HomePhone, 
                    mobileNumber = x.OtherPhone,
                    communicationConsent = ((Func<Array>)(() =>
                    {
                        var list = new List<object>();
                        if (x.TextConsent)
                            list.Add(new { method = "TEXT", consent = true });

                        if (x.VoiceConsent)
                            list.Add(new { method = "VOICE", consent = true });

                        if (x.EmailConsent)
                            list.Add(new { method = "EMAIL", consent = true });

                        return list.ToArray();
                    }))()
                }));

                if (responses.All(x => x.IsSuccessStatusCode))
                    await databaseHelper.SavePatientLastUpdatedDateForCompany(company, company.SyncData.CurrentDatabaseDate);
                else
                    throw new DataException($"Response for SyncPatientData failed for {company.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError($"Database: {company.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName} Method: SyncPatientData", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

I was asked about pulling the expression out of the first method to clean it up.  I've tried a few different ways to do this, but I always get the message "a lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted into an expression tree".

What I don't understand is why it has no problem with it when passed directly into the select but when I want to make the expression a variable I can't?  I'd like to find a way to make this work or understand why it works in one case but not the others?

Here are a some of the closer things I've tried so far:

```
        readonly Expression<Func<Patient, object>> patientSelect = x => {
        id = x.patient_id.ToString(),
                    internalId = x.patient_id.ToString(),
                    firstName = x.first_name,
                    middleName = x.middle_name,
                    lastName = x.last_name,
                    emailAddress = x.email,
                    homePhone = x.HomePhone, 
                    mobileNumber = x.OtherPhone,
                    communicationConsent = ((Func<Array>)(() =>
                    {
                        var list = new List<object>();
                        if (x.TextConsent)
                            list.Add(new { method = "TEXT", consent = true });

                        if (x.VoiceConsent)
                            list.Add(new { method = "VOICE", consent = true });

                        if (x.EmailConsent)
                            list.Add(new { method = "EMAIL", consent = true });

                        return list.ToArray();
                    }))()
                }));;

    private Expression<Func<Patient, dynamic>> patientSelectE(Patient p)
    {
        return p => new  
        {
            id = p.patient_id.ToString(),
            internalId = p.patient_id.ToString(),
            firstName = p.first_name,
            middleName = p.middle_name,
            lastName = p.last_name,                 
            emailAddress = p.email,
            homePhone = p.HomePhone,
            mobileNumber = p.OtherPhone, 
            communicationConsent = ((Func<Array>)(() =>
            {
                var list = new List<object>();
                if (p.TextConsent)
                    list.Add(new { method = "TEXT", consent = true });

                if (p.VoiceConsent)
                    list.Add(new { method = "VOICE", consent = true });

                if (p.EmailConsent)
                    list.Add(new { method = "EMAIL", consent = true });

                return list.ToArray();
            })) 
        });
    }
```

I know that it's because of the communicationConsent but I'm not sure how to get around it.  The reason its being done in this odd manner is that the IEnumerable is being serialized to json as the body of a post.  The body of the request must look like this:

```
    {
     "patients": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "middleName": "Q",
      "lastName": "EveryMan",
      "emailAddress": "test@test.com",
      "homePhone": "555-555-5555",
      "workPhone": "555-555-5555",
      "mobileNumber": "555-555-5555", 

      "communicationConsent": [
        {
          "method": "EMAIL",
          "consent": "true"
        },
        {
          "method": "TEXT",
          "consent": "true"
        },
        {
          "method": "VOICE",
          "consent": "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So you are using Linq to Entities or something like that? Otherwise the `Select` from Linq to Objects would just take a delegate and not an expression tree.

Comment: Is it fine if it outputs `new { method = "XXX", consent = false }` if `XXXConsent` is not true?

Comment: The question is very unclear. What is `data` in the first line of code? It's not clear how the first code block is called in "The method this is calling". Neither is is clear where `patientSelect` and `patientSelectE` would come. It's *probably* something with client-side evaluation that Entity Framework only does with expressions in a final select. Hard to tell.

Comment: I clarified the question to add the full method that works.  It is getting a collection of Patient Objects via a call using Dapper.  The collection is then serialized and posted.  The problem is the receiving for instance API won't take the property "first_name" so it is transformed to what they expect "firstName".

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown, exactly? The exception message you reported typically happens when you're trying to JSON-serialize an exception, so I suspect more is going on here than you think. Have you tried stepping through the code and inspecting the values of the objects leading up to the point where the error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Sweeper's first comment must be relevant. Your original code uses a plain delegate, not an expression tree.

You do not show exactly what `PostEntityData` wants for its third argument.

But presumably you could make simple methods like:

```
static object MapPatient(Patient x)
{
    return new {
                    id = x.patient_id.ToString(),
                    internalId = x.patient_id.ToString(),
                    firstName = x.first_name,
                    middleName = x.middle_name,
                    lastName = x.last_name,
                    emailAddress = x.email,
                    homePhone = x.HomePhone, 
                    mobileNumber = x.OtherPhone,
                    communicationConsent = GetCommConsent(x),
                };
}

static object[] GetCommConsent(Patient x)
{
    var list = new List<object>();
    if (x.TextConsent)
        list.Add(new { method = "TEXT", consent = true });

    if (x.VoiceConsent)
        list.Add(new { method = "VOICE", consent = true });

    if (x.EmailConsent)
        list.Add(new { method = "EMAIL", consent = true });

    return list.ToArray();
}
```

With that, in your original method you would write just

```
var responses = await manager.PostEntityData(
    "patients",
    appConfiguration.PatientUrl,
    data.Select(MapPatient)
    );
```

Comment: I was able to get this work except for a small hitch that causes a big problem.  When the select expression is factored into variable I am no longer able to json serialize the collection created this way I get the error:  "Self referencing loop detected for property 'ManifestModule' with type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'."
I don't understand why when I'm doing it inline its fine, but when passed as parameter a circular reference is created?

Comment: I feel you have now edited your question to the point where you are now asking something completely different. This makes my answer not fit the question as well as it hopefully did when I wrote it. Consider answering new questions instead if you run into new problems. For your new problem, try if you can boil it down to a minimal _reproducible_ example. It is hard for people here to read a wall of code and figure out where the problems may be. We are not ChatGPT, you know.

Comment: I was actually thinking that exact thing when I went to go update this question.  It technically does work even though the Serialization throws it off.  Let me see if I can revert the question to the previous.  Mark it as answered and then ask a different but related question.  
There are other ways to easily make the process work.  I just want to understand how / why / what abstracting the delegate changes.

Comment: As to the "wall of code" everyone seemed interested in the referenced methods, though it didn't feel to me like they were as relevant.

Comment: Good. If anyone is interested, I see your followup thread is [Why does extracting a Select Expression to a variable affect the collections ability to be serialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903313/)