# Why does extracting a Select Expression to a variable affect the collections ability to be serialized?

Tags: c#, linq, serialization

I had a method with several verbose calls in which a collection of Patients is being transformed into collection of Anonymous types via .Select().  When the Select Expression is defined inline the collection is able to be serialized to json without problem.  When the Select Expression is extracted out into a variable the serialization fails with the error:

"Self referencing loop detected for property 'ManifestModule' with type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'."

I do not see where / how a self referencing loop is occurring.
I do not understand how the inline vs abstracted expressions differ.

I tried playing with the serializer settings like ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize & PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects with no success.

```
    // This serializes just fine
    readonly Expression<Func<Appointment, object>> appointmentSelect = data => new { id = data.id.ToString(), patientId = data.patientId, calendarId = data.calendarId, date = Convert.ToDateTime(data.date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"), typeId = data.typeId, locationId = data.locationId, summary = data.summary, details = data.details, cancelled = data.cancelled, duration = data.duration, blocked = false };
    //This will not serialize.  Why?
    readonly Expression<Func<Patient, object>> patientSelect2 = x => new { id = x.patient_id.ToString(), internalId = x.patient_id.ToString(), firstName = x.first_name, middleName = x.middle_name, lastName = x.last_name, emailAddress = x.email, homePhone = x.HomePhone, mobileNumber = x.OtherPhone, communicationConsent = GetCommConsent(x) };
 
    //This will not serialize.  Why?
    private Expression<Func<Patient, object>> patientSelect(Patient p)
    {
        return x => new
        {
            id = p.patient_id.ToString(),
            internalId = p.patient_id.ToString(),
            firstName = p.first_name,
            middleName = p.middle_name,
            lastName = p.last_name,
            emailAddress = p.email,
            homePhone = p.HomePhone,
            mobileNumber = p.OtherPhone,
            communicationConsent = GetCommConsent(p)
        };
    }
    private static object[] GetCommConsent(Patient p)
    {
        var list = new List<object>();
        if (p.TextConsent)
            list.Add(new { method = "TEXT", consent = true });

        if (p.VoiceConsent)
            list.Add(new { method = "VOICE", consent = true });

        if (p.EmailConsent)
            list.Add(new { method = "EMAIL", consent = true });

        return list.ToArray();
    }

    public async Task SyncData(ProcessType processType)
    {
        var companies = await databaseHelper.GetCompanies(processType);
          
        foreach (var company in companies)
        { 
            var manager = new ContentManager(company, appConfiguration);

            // This will serialize perfectly
            // company.Patients is an IEnumerable<Patient> 
            await ProcessResponses(company, await manager.PostEntityData("patients", appConfiguration.PatientUrl, company.Patients.Select(x => new
                {
                    id = x.patient_id.ToString(),
                    internalId = x.patient_id.ToString(),
                    firstName = x.first_name,
                    middleName = x.middle_name,
                    lastName = x.last_name, 
                    emailAddress = x.email,
                    homePhone = x.HomePhone,
                    mobileNumber = x.OtherPhone,                        
                    communicationConsent = ((Func<Array>)(() =>
                    {
                        var list = new List<object>();
                        if (x.TextConsent)
                            list.Add(new { method = "TEXT", consent = true });

                        if (x.VoiceConsent)
                            list.Add(new { method = "VOICE", consent = true });

                        if (x.EmailConsent)
                            list.Add(new { method = "EMAIL", consent = true });

                        return list.ToArray();
                    }))()
                })), databaseHelper.SavePatientLastUpdatedDate);

                //This same call causes the serialization error
                await ProcessResponses(company, await manager.PostEntityData("patients", appConfiguration.PatientUrl,
                    company.Patients.AsQueryable().Select(p => patientSelect(p))), databaseHelper.SavePatientLastUpdatedDate);

                //This also causes the serialization error
                await ProcessResponses(company, await manager.PostEntityData("patients", appConfiguration.PatientUrl,
                    company.Patients.AsQueryable().Select(patientSelect2)), databaseHelper.SavePatientLastUpdatedDate);
                
                //Works perfectly but does not contain a nested statement body
                await ProcessResponses(company, await manager.PostEntityData("appointments", appConfiguration.AppointmentUrl,
                    company.Appointments.AsQueryable().Select(appointmentSelect)), databaseHelper.SaveAppointmentLastUpdatedDate);
            } 
        } 
    }
    private async Task ProcessResponses(Company company, HttpResponseMessage[] responses, Func<Company, Task<int>> func)
    {
        if (responses.Any(x => !x.IsSuccessStatusCode))
        {
            foreach (var response in responses.Where(x => !x.IsSuccessStatusCode))
            {
                var request = await response.RequestMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                    
            }
        }
        await func(company);
    }
```

These are the relevant classes in the ContentManager object that is being called:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage[]> PostEntityData<T>(string collectionName, string url, IEnumerable<T> data)
    { 
        var batches = SplitCollectionIntoSmallerCollections(data.ToList()); 
        var content = new List<StringContent>(batches.Count); 

        foreach (var batch in batches)
        {
            content.Add(await CreateContent(collectionName, batch)); 
        }

        List<HttpResponseMessage> responses = new List<HttpResponseMessage>(batches.Count());
        foreach (var item in content)
        {
            var result = await PostHttpContent(company, url, item);
            responses.Add(result);
        }

        return responses.ToArray(); 
    }
    private List<IEnumerable<T>> SplitCollectionIntoSmallerCollections<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        var totalRecords = data.Count();
         
        var batchSize = 500;
        var batchless = totalRecords % batchSize;
        // If you have a remainder you need to add an extra non-full collection
        var totalBatches = batchless == 0 ? totalRecords / batchSize : (totalRecords / batchSize) + 1;            
        var batches = new List<IEnumerable<T>>(totalBatches);

        for (int i = 0; i < totalBatches; i++)
        {
            batches.Add(data.Skip(batchSize * i).Take(batchSize));
        } 
          
        return batches;
    }
    
    public async Task<StringContent> CreateContent(string collectionName, object data)
    {
        try
        {
            var auth = await BuildUpdoxAuth(databaseHelper, company.DatabaseName);
            var request = new DataRequest(auth, data); 
            
            //This is where the error will occur! 
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request).Replace("\"data\":", $"\"{collectionName}\":"), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 
             
            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostHttpContent(Company company, string url, StringContent content)
    {
         //Implementation shouldn't be relevant but I'll add it if requested
    }
```

Have I abstracted the Select Expression incorrectly?
If it is correct, why does extracting the expression create self referencing loop while leaving it inline does not?
I would like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: FWIW, there are other ways to accomplish this.  For instance I could add a transformation method to Patient that returns a PatientDTO with all the correct property names for the post. I tried to reduce the code for brevity, the method normally makes 6 different entity calls this way.  I left the appointments collection as an example.
Patient is different because of it's communicationConsent collection. 
I want to understand why the behavior appears inconsistent compared to declaring the expression inline.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not see where / how a self referencing loop is occurring.

It's not occurring in your object model.  Your code is throwing some other exception and the serialization framework is trying to serialize that exception when it encounters the exception you're catching.  Your first clue that this reference loop has nothing to do with your code is that the name of the property is `ManifestModule`, which is not a property of any type you're dealing with directly.

> I do not understand how the inline vs abstracted expressions differ.

The inline expression is not an expression tree but a delegate -- a function -- because it's being used with an `IEnumerable` rather than an `IQueryable`.  In other words, the call that works is `company.Patients.Select()` while the ones that fail are `company.Patients.AsQueryable().Select()`.
The function can call another function, no problem.  But that function call can't be translated into SQL and run on the database server, so the `AsQueryable().Select()` fails.

Similarly, the Appointment example works on an `IQueryable` because there's no function call, so that expression tree *can* be translated into something that can run on the server.

So the fact that you've pulled the expression into a variable has nothing to do with the different behavior; the critical difference is that you're calling a different extension method: `Enumerable.Select()` vs. `Queryable.Select()`.

Comment: I believe I understand what you are saying.  At the same time if I remove the .AsQueryable() and make it just:  
await ProcessResponses(company, await manager.PostEntityData("patients", appConfiguration.PatientUrl,
                        company.Patients.Select(p => patientSelect)), databaseHelper.SavePatientLastUpdatedDate); 
This should be against IEnumerable instead of the IQueryable, but the same error occurs during serialization.  I thought removing the IQueryable would make them functionally the same.

Comment: What is the correct way to take the working Select example and extract the working expression into a delegate that can be used with .Select() off an IEnumerable?

Comment: @jrandomuser what is the declared type of the `Patients` property?

Comment: Patients, Appointments, etc are all IEnumerable<T>? collections off of company.  So Patients is of type IEnumerable<Patient>?.  
This was of particular interest to me at one point because you'll notice the method "PostEntityData" takes the type IEnumerable<T> as data.  I was skeptical that I could even pass the data to this method because of the select translation.  Technically what I'm passing is a collection of "anonymous types".  I was passing it as IEnumerable<object> at one point but it takes it both ways so I left in the Type.